# ReactJS - radio button onChange event not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
render() {

    return (

        <div className="main-block">
            <h1>Registration</h1>

            <form>
                <hr />
                <div className="account-type">
                    <input type="radio" onChange={this.handleUserType} value="1" checked={this.state.userType === "1"}/>
                    <label htmlFor="radioOne" className="radio">one</label>
                    <input type="radio" value="2" onChange={this.handleUserType} checked={this.state.userType === "2"}/>
                    <label htmlFor="radioTwo" className="radio">two</label>
                </div>
    ...
    ...
```

Where `handleUserType` is defined outside of the `render` function:

```
handleUserType = event => {
    console.log("here")
    this.setState({
        userType: event.target.value
    });
};
```

They render perfectly fine, but whenever i click one of the radio buttons, the `onChange` function is not called (i.e i'm not getting the `console.log("here")`)

What is the problem?

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: No i didn't....

Comment: Your code (assuming [the rest of it looks something like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-hill-ctci3)) works fine.

Comment: Works fine for me [`sandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-wildflower-tc82v)

Answer (score 0):

React make it so that only the JavaScript is the "source of truth" therefore clicking on the radio button won't trigger an `onChange` event since nothing has changed in the JS. Use an `onClick` event handler instead.

Edit: After further investigation the `onChange` event you posted should work.

Comment: Then i'm getting the console error ```You provided a checked prop to a form field without an onChange handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use defaultChecked. Otherwise, set either onChange or readOnly```

Comment: @R10t In my experience this is not correct, onChange works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted a codesandbox of your request below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-kcdrs

I wrote two components, one as a class and the other as a function. Both work correctly with onChange. I would need to see more of your code to attempt to help you pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { userType: "1" };
      }

      handleUserType = e => {
        this.setState({ userType: e.target.value });
      };

      render() {
        const { userType } = this.state;
        return (
          <form>
            <div className="account-type">
              <input
                type="radio"
                onChange={this.handleUserType}
                value="1"
                checked={userType === "1"}
              />
              <label htmlFor="radioOne" className="radio">
                one
              </label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                value="2"
                onChange={this.handleUserType}
                checked={userType === "2"}
              />
              <label htmlFor="radioTwo" className="radio">
                two
              </label>
            </div>
          </form>
        );
      }
    }

    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-lamarr-ezk06